# can import the classes present in the remote system?

Tags: java

i have a server machine where all the helper jars and classes present, which i want to use. is it possible to import those classes in my application?

Comment: What do you mean by import? Classloading via RMI? Loading jars via WebStart or Applet?

Comment: in my java source file. can use import statement for those classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can import classes defined in those JAR files.  But you need to have copies of the JAR files on the machine where you are building your application, and probably on the machines on which you will be running it.

If your application is an applet, it can downloaded the JARs at runtime, but that requires the JARs to be signed.  There is also the option of using [Java Web Start](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javawebstart/index.jsp).